# android studio manifest.xml error - it has green area(can't solve)

Tags: android, android-manifest

I used the android studio 2.3.2 , I find the manifest has some error. I don't know how to solve it. Could you help what problem is and how to solve.
Q1 : many green area. why?
Q2 : permission can't use?

many thanks.
[image]

Comment: can you please post menifest.xml code?

Comment: Typo? `uses-permission`

Comment: The yellow box definitely tells you the error

Comment: my manifest.xml

Answer (score 3):

Permission tag is `<uses-permission />` and not `<user-permission />`

So your Write External Storage permission tag will look like

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have used wrong permission type. You must replace all your `user-permission` to `uses-permission`.

Answer (score 0):

my Manifest.xml
, but when I used the other class, check the permission is wrong.
  int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( RegistationActivity3.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA );

Manifest.permission.CAMERA ==> permission is red color.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.test.myApp">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity.MainActivity"/>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity.MainActivity"/>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.RegistationActivity1"
            android:label="Registation"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
           <!--
                                 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
                                 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity.MainActivity"/>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.RegistationActivity2"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_registation2"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.RegistationActivity1"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity.RegistationActivity1"/>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.RegistationActivity3"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_registation3"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.RegistationActivity2"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity.RegistationActivity2"/>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ForgotPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_forgot_password"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.hkwgs.hkwgs.activity.LoginActivity"/>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```